# Applying for a PhD, do academics hold grudges?

Tags: phd, advisor

During my BSc, I had an overall OK-ish relationship with my adviser. For clarification, my adviser was not a supervisor (I've seen the words being used interchangeably in some countries and unis). He was just someone I went to if I had questions or concerns about my course.

At the end of my degree, I blew up an internship interview with him, and I am worried if this will affect my chances of getting a PhD in the same department (but in completely different research group).

Comment: Do academics hold grudges?  Some do, some don't.  You should not spend time worrying about it.

Comment: What is the question? Is there a question?

Comment: The real question here is "Should keep beating myself up for a botched interview two years ago?", to which the answer is obviously "no". You appear to be blowing the entire episode way, way out of proportion in your head. A scenario where your advisor holds a "grudge" against you based on this seems to me, absent evidence to the contrary, to be bordering on science fiction. On the other hand, it is not entirely out of the question that someone on the admission committee will be aware of this episode. Chances that they will consider it as big a deal as you still do, though, are close to zero.

Comment: Finally, if *this episode* is the reason why you are trying to avoid asking your advisor for a letter of reference, then, if I'm being honest, this seems a bit silly to me and I would advise you to reconsider. Of course, it may be that you have other, more rational reasons not to use him as one of your references.

Comment: So how does his assessment of you being an inadequate fit for an intern position affect your perceived capacity as a PhD student two years later?..

Comment: Yes, many academics hold grudges. Examples abound.

Answer (score 1):

> do academics hold grudges?

It depends on the context and the personality of the academic. But in general there is no reason to believe that the distribution of academics who do hold grudges is in any way different from the general population. So in summary: yes, some academics do hold grudges, or at least do not want to invest in someone who has disappointed them once.

Comment: It might be worth adding that someone might hold some kind of grudge, yet be able to behave professionally and write a fair letter.

Answer (score -1):

Unless the professor you mentioned is on the hiring committee for your PhD, I’m not sure what can be done. Don’t write an email! I teach undergrad and grad students, so I want to put myself in your shoes. I tried writing out your problem, but it feels silly:

“Dear Doctor So-and-So,

I’m not sure if you remember me but I wanted to let you know I’m applying for a PhD at Your Uni with Dr. Other Person. I wanted to reach out because I interviewed with you a few years ago for an internship but my wifi was cutting out and, during the interview, I soon realized the internship didn’t fit my skill set. I wanted to apologize for the lack of professionalism.”

If I received an e-mail like this from a student, I would be confused. I would probably be nice and write back “Don’t worry about it. Good luck!” That’s it. Why even send an email?

I’m sorry you’re worried about this prior episode but it shouldn’t affect your PhD prospects with another professor. If nothing else, this happened during the pandemic. I feel like a lot of my colleagues have been much more generous towards students because of this time in history.

Comment: I don't think such a letter is needed or helpful. The matter was likely long forgotten. Why bring it up again? If that person is one who would hold a grudge you are just picking at a sore.

Comment: Sorry, that’s what I meant: the letter would NOT be helpful. After writing it out, I felt silly.